# Send email when asterisk fails to call

Tags: asterisk, sip

I have an asterisk which is originating various calls.

Which is the most elegant way to send and email (or more generally trigger an event) when it fails to call a certain amount of time in a row?

For instance: When  more than 20 calls fail because of insufficient credit, send an email.

My solution: Schedule using crontab a scripts that grep log files (cdr-csv) and do the requested operation.

Answer (score 1):

Most elegant/lower cpu usage is use AMI event listener and trigger UserEvent with request of email.

To trigger UserEvent you can use h extension

```
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/trunk/${EXTEN},,o)
exten => h,1,ExecIF($[ ${DIALSTATUS} != "ANSWERED" ]?UserEvent(TrunkFailed,Status: ${DIALSTATUS})
```

Comment: Indeed, it is the most elegant way. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any good link to write a new UserEvent? This doc is not enough: http://the-asterisk-book.com/1.6/applikationen-userevent.html, and nor https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/asterisk-the-future/9780596510480/re134.html is complete. Where should one write le logic for the event? manager.conf (that configures the manager interface that receives the event) is not the right place..

Comment: Shouldn't suffice an AGI?

Comment: You should use AMI event listener and read event. User event just send event so it can be read via AMI.